# Django receive post result from curl

Tags: django, curl

I've created a function that's supposed to receive post data from a curl request and return a result. I've disabled csrf for the view so the error I'm getting is I can't parse the json.

Here's my view

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_user(request):
    response = {'status': None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        ...
```

I get this error on the terminal

```
Internal Server Error: /api-user-create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
  response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
  response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
  return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/samuel/Documents/code/binabikers/delivery/views.py", line 14, in create_user
  data = json.loads(request.body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
  raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
[01/Aug/2017 03:58:24] "POST /api-user-create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 85347
```

which implies this is not the best way to read json from curl request like this

```
curl -X POST -d "username=john&password=john2&email=john@email.com&first_name=john&last_name=smith" http://localhost:8000/api-user-create/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no data in in `request.body`,  that's why it's showing error, the data in the request.POST method, so you can directory load the request.POST content into json format or you can use

```
request.POST.get("your parameter")

1. if requset.method =="POST":
    data = json.loads(request.POST)
2. if requset.method =="POST":
    rg = request.POST.get
    print (rg('your parameter')
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I've later found out the input on the curl request wasn't valid formatted json here's the way to properly format it

```
curl -X POST -d '{"user-type": "user", "username":"john", "password":"john2", "email": "john@email.com", "f", "last-name":"smith"}' http://localhost:8000/api-user-create/
```